# Example of a variadic templated method being inherited from a base class

Tags: templates, inheritance, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to use the variadic template feature of C++11 for functions. Basically, my requirement is that I have a base class with a function, say,

```
user_defined_function()
```

This function cannot be defined in the base class but whenever a developer creates a derived class, she may want to implement this method according to her requirement. However, the method may have any number of any types of arguments and may return any type. I was thinking that I could have this method as one with a variadic template, but since I am dealing with inheritance of the method, I think it is tricky. Could someone give an example of doing this? Following is my code but I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

```
// base.h
class Base 
{
public: 
   template<typename R, typename... arguments>
   R user_defined_function(arguments... parameters);
};
```

```
// derived.h
class Derived:public Base
{
public:
  template<int, float, int, double>
  int user_defined_function(float, int, double);
};
```

```
// derived.cc
int Derived::user_defined_function(float, int, double)
{/* implementation */ }
```

Comment: Why is it declared in the base class if it cannot be defined by the base class? Who will call the function and how? Perhaps look into CRTP ("curiously recurring template pattern"), which provides the base class with access to derived members via templating.

Comment: actually the base class kind of defines the structure of the derived classes. It is more like an interface. When someone derives a class from this Base class, he or she might need to implement this function, depending on their requirement. The reason why I put it in the base class is to allow a user to know what functions he or she can implement in the derived class. The invocation is done inside another method in the Base class, which I did not show above.

Comment: A more complete example might help. It's not clear what role templates play, or if you want a virtual function. One definite thing, though, is that the derived class can't specialize a member template of the base class. Aside from virtual functions, C++ currently lacks formal interface specifications. It sounds like you may be looking for something like the proposed "concepts" feature, which has been delayed to at least ~2017. In the meantime, comments are the best substitute.

Comment: why do you say that the derived class cannot specialize the member template of the base class? To put it in a crude way, I would like to have a virtual function in the base class that could accept templates. But this is not possible.

Comment: in my case, would it be better if I just overload the user_defined_function() in the derived classes?

Comment: Do you need polymorphism? I.e. do you need to support `Base* p = ...; p->user_defined_function(..);`?

Comment: no, I don't need to have an instance of the base class to access this function in any situation.

Comment: If you just want implementers of `Derived` to be notified if they forget to provide some function, this problem is solved by Concepts. In your case, it seems you can pass information to the base class ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1b26e8fde1fa9b5)), but note that derivation increases coupling (I therefore made it `private`, that helps a bit).

Comment: The statement "I don't need to have an instance of the base class to access this function in any situation." does not jive with "The invocation is done inside another method in the `Base` class, which I did not show above." If you want methods of `Base` to invoke the implementation of `user_defined_function` in a derived class, it needs to either be `virtual` - impossible for a template member function - or you need to use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution to my problem. The issue was with my design. I decided not to have,

```
    user_defined_function()
```

inside the base class. Instead, I created another singleton class inside which I have this variadic templated method. Then I have instantiated this class inside the base class described above and made the instance public. Now, using this object, I can invoke the variadic function from all derived classes. It works fine.